# Probability of Union of 3 Sets

Tags: probability, statistics, elementary-set-theory

Say you know $P(F)$, $P(G)$, $P(H)$, $P(FG)$, $P(FH)$, $P(GH)$ and $P(FGH)$.

How do you find $P(F^CG^CH)$?

$P(F^CG^CH)$

= $P((F^CG^C)H)$ by commutative property.

= $P((F \cup G)^CH)$ by De Morgan's

= ... ?

Comment: Try drawing a Venn diagram.

Comment: @JairTaylor I want to be able to do these questions without having to draw a Venn Diagram for each one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You were on the right track.

$\begin{align}
& P(F^C\cap G^C\cap H)
\\ &= P((F^C\cap G^C)\cap H)&& \text{by associative property.}
\\ &= P((F \cup G)^C\cap H) &&\text{by De Morgan's}
\\[2ex] &= P(H)-P((F\cup G)\cap H) && \text{by relative complementation}
\\ &=P(H)-P((F\cap H)\cup(G\cap H)) &&\text{by distribution}
\\ &=P(H)-P(F\cap H)-P(G\cap H)+P((F\cap H)\cap(G\cap H)) && \text{by PIE (Principle of Inclusion and Exclusion)}
\\ &=P(H)-P(F\cap H)-P(G\cap H)+P(F\cap G\cap H) && \text{by Distribution}
\\ \end{align}$

Answer (score 1):

Observe that
$$
P(F^c\cap G^c\cap H)=P(H)-P(F\cap H)-P(G\cap H)+P(F\cap G\cap H).
$$
Subtract the things that are in $F\cap H$ and $G\cap H$ but then we subtracted the things in $F\cap G\cap H$ twice so we add it back.

Comment: How did you know $P(F^c\cap G^c\cap H)=P(H)-P(F\cap H)-P(G\cap H)+P(F\cap G\cap H)$ ?

Comment: @A_for_Abacus It's as easy as PIE.  (Principle of Inclusion and Exclusion).

Comment: @GrahamKemp Isn't Principle of Inclusion and Exclusion for unions?

Comment: Yes, @A_for_Abacus, and $H$ can be written as a union making it applicable. $$H= (F^\complement\cap G^\complement \cap H)~\cup~(F\cap H)\cup (G\cap H)$$ Of note: the first conjunct is disjoint from the other two, while the latter two conjuncts intersect, so: $$\mathsf P(H)= \mathsf P(F^\complement\cap G^\complement \cap H)~+~\mathsf P(F\cap H) +\mathsf P (G\cap H) - \mathsf P(F\cap G\cap H)$$ Then we just rearrange.

Answer (score 0):

Found the answer.

Theorems used in this solution:

$P(A^C) + P(A) = P(Ω)$

$P(A \cup B) = P(A) + P(B) - P(AB)$

[image]